# What defines a "complete" Luigi task?

Tags: python-2.7, luigi

I am working on building my first Luigi pipeline, and I am currently testing tasks individually before building my dependencies. During testing, I am using a version of the following main method to build a task:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    headers = dict()
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json"

    luigi.build[(CSVValidator(jsonfile = '/sample_input/sample_csv.json',
                docfile = None,
                error_limit = 2,
                order_fields = 3,
                output_file = 'validation_is_us.txt',
                header = headers)])

    luigi.run()
```

This is what my csv_validator looks like:

```
class CSVValidator(luigi.Task):
    jsonfile = luigi.Parameter()
    docfile = luigi.Parameter()
    error_limit = luigi.Parameter()
    order_fields = luigi.Parameter()
    output_file = luigi.Parameter()
    header = luigi.DictParameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.output_file + "/csv_validator_data_%s.txt" % time.time())

    def run(self):
        output_file = self.output().open('w')
        files = {}
        data = {}
        files["jsonfile"] = open(self.jsonfile, 'rb')
        files["docfile"] = open(self.docfile, 'rb')
        data["error_limit"] = self.error_limit
        data["order_fields"] = self.order_fields
        r = requests.post(*****~~~~~*****~~~~~,
                      headers=headers,
                      data=data, files=files)
        task_response = r.text.encode(encoding="UTF-8")
        print type(task_response)
        print(task_response)
        jsontaskdata = json.loads(task_response)
        json.dump(jsontaskdata, output_file)
        print("validated")
        output_file.close()
```

This task, however, is never actually run. Instead the luigi central scheduler claims that this task is already complete:

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 2 tasks of which:
* 1 complete ones were encountered:
    - 1 CSVValidator(...)
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 Downloader(...)
```

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

Other tasks I have created, Downloader for example, do run successfully every time. What defines a complete task here? I don't understand what it means.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Target-object which is returned by the output-method defines whether a Task is finished or not.

The object might be created if a certain output-file already exists, or some other condition, including the availability of external resources. For example, in `luigi.contrib.esindex.py` the (check for) existance of an ElasticSearch index in some remote cluster will create the Target-object and tell you that a task (CopyIndex) is complete.

You might also want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638943/4125622

And this discussion: https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/595